# ServiceManager can't find classes by full namespace when testing with phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, servicemanager

I'm retrieving instances from the ServiceManager by their full class names in some cases, for example:

```
$someThing = $serviceManager->get('MyModule\Some\Nice\Lib\SomeThing');
```

This works pretty well for HTTP MVC requests, however, when using phpunit, the ServiceManager can't find it. (It throws a `Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException` exception with message "`Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get` was unable to fetch or create an instance for ...")

I'm using the default testing bootstrap example from [the docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/unit-testing.html) and I experience this issue in two different projects on different mashines, so I guess this is a general problem.

My first guess was that it has something to do with MVC or application, becuase this is most likely the only real difference between testing and http. I even dumped the SM instances in both modes and compared them with each other, looked through the sources and searched the web.

Unfortunately, I can't paste any code due to my labor contract. However, as I said, I think this is a general problem so you should be able to easily reproduce it.

Does anybody know what is causing this issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to locate the problem.

When you create an instance with its full class name using `ServiceManager`, it won't in fact be able to create it by default. However, if possible, it delegates the task to the abstract factories that are attached to it.

Now, when you create a Di instance using the DiFactory, the factory registers a `DiAbstractServiceFactory` to SM. And, you guess it, this abstract factory is able to instantiate classes by their full class names.

I've rarely used `Di` in this project (because I didn't really feel comfortable with it and used it wrong in the beginning; I know better now), which is why the only point where I instantiate `Di` is inside the `onBootstrap()` method of a module. This is fine in MVC context, however, as `onBootstrap()` is an HTTP MVC event handler, it won't be invoked in my testing application. Thus, no `Di` is instaniated at any time, thus, `ServiceManager` hasn't got the `DiAbstractServiceFactory` attached to it, thus it can't delegate the `get()` call, thus it fails to instantiate classes by their full class names.

It's as simple as that! :-)

The obvious solution: Create a `Di` instance inside the testing application.

Comment: you forgot to mention most important part in your question: that you used Zend\Di and SM was merely a proxy. :P

Comment: Can you share the sample code. I also have the same problem and couldn't get over it.

Comment: There is not much sample code to share. Simply invoke `$serviceManager->get('Di');`  somewhere.

Comment: I have written the code based on http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/unit-testing.html So in this can you please tell where and all the changes has to be done so that we can overcome the issue?

Comment: So have I. Just put it somewhere where it's always being executed (for example in the Bootstrap.php).

Answer (score 0):

make sure you added your module to test config:

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'MyModule',
        //...
    ),
    //...
);
```

otherwise ModuleManager will not try to load it, hence module autoloader will not be registered

Comment: The module is loaded, I can also instantiate it directly using the `new` keyword.

Comment: then probably configuration for your service is in application level config and not loaded during tests?